# Variable filter criteria for filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'd like to filter an array with information of many photos like this, but the filter should be variable (argument and data type of argument):

```
var photos = [
  {
    lat: -15,
    lng: -20,
    alt: 381,
    date: "2016-12-12",
    comment: "Text1" // and many more arguments like file size, bitdepth, iso, ...
  }, 
  {
    lat: -17,
    lng: -22,
    alt: 1381,
    date: "2016-11-11",
    comment: "Text2" // and many more arguments like file size, bitdepth, iso, ...
  },
  {
    lat: -25,
    lng: -30,
    alt: 1000,
    date: "2016-10-10",
    comment: "Text3" // and many more arguments like file size, bitdepth, iso, ...
  },
];
```

Now I'd like to filter the array using the method

```
array.filter(callbackfn[, thisArg])
```

But the filter criteria and the data types of data looking for vary (e. g. search for elements with '(lat < -15)' or '(lng > -25) && (alt > 1000)' or 'comment == "Text2"' but I don't see how this can be done. Obviously that

```
function filterMetaData(obj, filterString) {
    if(filterString) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var result = photos.filter(filterMetaData, "lat < -18");
```

does not work, since "lat < -18" is a string and not interpreted like a criteria, so if(filterString) is always true.

How can this be done?
Thx, Markus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function as parameter

```js
function filterMetaData(fn) {
    return function (o) {
        return fn(o);
    };
}

var photos = [{ lat: -15, lng: -20, alt: 381, date: "2016-12-12", comment: "Text1" }, { lat: -17, lng: -22, alt: 1381, date: "2016-11-11", comment: "Text2" }, { lat: -25, lng: -30, alt: 1000, date: "2016-10-10",  comment: "Text3" }],
    result = photos.filter(filterMetaData(function (o) { return o.lat < -18; }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 destructuring with [object property assignment pattern](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern)

```js
function filterMetaData(fn) {
    return function (o) {
        return fn(o);
    };
}

var photos = [{ lat: -15, lng: -20, alt: 381, date: "2016-12-12", comment: "Text1" }, { lat: -17, lng: -22, alt: 1381, date: "2016-11-11", comment: "Text2" }, { lat: -25, lng: -30, alt: 1000, date: "2016-10-10",  comment: "Text3" }],
    result = photos.filter(filterMetaData(({ lat, lng, alt, date }) => lat < -15 || (lng > -25 && alt > 1000)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Trying to make the function user friendly: How can I modify it only needs the filter criteria e. g. `(lat < -15) || (lng > -25 && (alt > 1000)` and not `(o.lat < -15) || (o.lng > -25 && (o.alt > 1000)` ?

Comment: @Markus, maybe the second approach works for you with ES6.

Comment: Additionally I saw that `result = photos.filter(filterMetaData(function (o) { return (o.lat < -18) && (o.lat > -25); }))` works but `result = photos.filter(filterMetaData(function (o) { return (-25 < o.lat < -18); }))` does not. How come?

Comment: it compares the first part `-25 < o.lat `, which gives `true` or `false` with the rest, so it tests either `true < -18` or `false  < -18`. both yields to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
   data =  photos.filter(function(a){
return (a.lat < -15) ||(a.lng > -25 && (a.alt > 1000) || (a.comment == "Text2"); 
});
consoe.log(data)
```